# How to write a function in Julia that accepts a variable number of arguments?

Tags: function, julia

I am trying to write a function that should be allowed to take in a variable number of arguments.  However, it's not too clear how I can do that in Julia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Julia, as with many other languages, there exists the ability to write **Vararg Functions**. These functions allow for a variable number of arguments to be passed in. [Here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions-1) a quick reference to the Julia docs on this idea and an example:

```
julia> varargs(a,b,c...) = (a,b,c)
varargs (generic function with 1 method)

julia> varargs(5, 10)
(5, 10, ())

julia> varargs(3,4,5)
(3, 4, (5,))

julia> varargs(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
(10, 20, (30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80))

julia> d = (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

julia> varargs(1,2,d)
(1, 2, ((2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),))
```

To reiterate, the magic is happening here when we define the `varargs` function and write `c...`. This notation enables the whole concept of variable-sized arguments.

Comment: To expand your answer, I think it would make sense to note that the effect of the three dots `...`, depending on the context, is referred to as _slurping_ (in the signature of a function definition) and _splatting_ (in a function call). Also, you might want to show how to dispatch on such a function with a variable number of input arguments, i.e. the parametric `VarArg` type.

Comment: Vararg, not VarArg